# Remove system border from html element

Tags: html, css

[image: Pic related.]  <- I mean this dotted border (top-left corner is shown).

It supposed to be a button with link. It looks great, but when I click on it, browser draws a border around it. If I remove the `<a>` from code and click again, border won't be drawn

CSS:

```
#button{
        padding: 0.5em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: #B3C833;
        font-family: 'Consolas',monospace;
        font-size: 3em;
        display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
    <div id="button">
        <span id="pref">http://</span><span id="addr">example.com</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: You need to style the `a` element, not the `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this porperty:

```
a {
  outline:none;
}
```

Comment: @MatthewJohnson I tried to create a googleplay-like button. That «Buy/Install» button. It does not have outline.

Comment: I just went through the play store, and you're right.  Most of the links still highlight, but it skips over some of the links.  Not all companies keep accessibility in mind, but that doesn't mean we should ignore it.  Test your site by navigating through it with only the keyboard (tab, shift+tab).  Without the outline, it's hard to keep track of where the focus is.

Answer (score 1):

That border is there for accessibility, and shouldn't be removed.  It allows people that are disabled and accessing your site via keyboard to see where the focus is.

Check out [outlinenone.com](http://outlinenone.com/)

If you don't mind losing a portion of your traffic, you can remove it anyway with:

```
a {
  outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Though this isn't really an answer to the question, It is something  should think about before you decide to remove (or not remove) the outline. No need for a vote down I think.

Comment: @MichielReyers I agree on the no need for a down vote.  I think accessibility should always be kept in mind, and I'm willing to lose the rep to keep the answer posted.  I'll adjust the answer to include how to remove it anyway.

Comment: I understand this, believe me. Guys at outlinenone.com have provided alternatives so I'll think about using one of them. Default outline is just looking too ugly.